# Linking a MySQL table to a dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, dropdown

I am trying to link my database table to a drop down list, so the dropdown list is filled with values from my table. Can any help me or have any advice?
This is my entire dogdropdown.php

```
    <?php

 // set up connection parameters
 $dbHost        = 'localhost';
$databaseName   = 'i insert my db name here';
$username       = 'i insert my username here';
$password       = 'i insert my password here';

// make the database connection
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$databaseName;charset=utf8", "$username", "$password");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   // enable error handling
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);           // turn off emulation mode

 $mysqli=mysqli_connect($dbHost,$username,$password,$databaseName);
?>



  <h3> Search dogs</h3>
<select>
<?php
$stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM dog");// wrap off and use only query to run
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

/* Get the number of rows */
$num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows;

/* Get the result */
$result = $stmt->get_result();

while ($dropdown = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
print_r($dropdown);
// echo '<option value="Dog_Id"' . $dropdown['id'] . '">'.$dropdown['id'].'</option>';// add text to dropdown
 }
 ?>
  </select>
```

I would like the drop down to be filled with values from the table dog,and the Dog_Id colum. 
The database connection seems to be ok as no errors are showing!

Comment: what is the issue with the current code

Comment: Could you post the result of `var_dump($res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC));`

Comment: @Lauren D, why have done connection 2 times : with PDO and mysqli ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue that is faced is `$dropdown['dog']` try replacing it with $dropdown['id']. As, I suppose there is *no Column with the name dog* in **DOG table**

```
<h3> Search dogs</h3>
<select>
<?php
$stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM dog");// wrap off and use only query to run
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

/* Get the number of rows */
$num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows;

/* Get the result */
$result = $stmt->get_result();

 while ($dropdown = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    print_r($dropdown);
   // echo '<option value="Dog_Id"' . $dropdown['id'] . '">'.$dropdown['id'].'</option>';// add text to dropdown
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying it still just shows an empty dropdown list.

Comment: just do `echo "<pre>".$dropdown."</pre>"`; in while loop and let me know the output @LaurenD

Comment: `code`  <h3> Search dogs</h3>
          <select>
<?php
$stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM dog");// wrap off and use only query to run
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
while ($dropdown = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option value="Dog_Id"' . $dropdown['id'] . '">'.$dropdown['id'].'</option>';// add text to dropdown
    echo "<pre>".$dropdown."</pre>";
}
?>
</select>

Comment: it still is an empty drop down :(

Comment: @LaurenD, not this just do `print_r($dropdown);` . Sorry I told to echo instead it was print_r. And let me know the output. You'll get get an empty dropdown only, I just want to get the value of $dropdown array

Comment: <h3> Search dogs</h3>
<select>
<?php
$stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM dog");// wrap off and use only query to run
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
while ($dropdown = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option value="Dog_Id"' . $dropdown['id'] . '">'.$dropdown['id'].'</option>';// add text to dropdown
    print_r($dropdown);
}
?>
</select>

Comment: @LaurenD, please check my edited answer replace it with your code, and run it in browser. you'll get an array as a response. just paste that response that you get on browser

Comment: i copied and pasted your answer and still absolutely nothing :( just an empty drop down still! :(

Comment: @LaurenD, like I said earlier u won't get anything in dropdown. Are you that new to PHP,  that you are not able to get anything. There issue in your query I think so that's why I told you to do so. But since you're not getting anything its hard to help you

Comment: @LaurenD, check my updated answer. and please paste and replace it with your code. AsI've commented dropdown, so i guess won't be able to get multiple options

Comment: @LaurenD, can you paste your full code, with db screenshot as well

Comment: Nehal i pasted my full code in the edited section aswell, couldnt see anywhere for me to attach a screenshot. thanks for looking, lauren